# Hyperledger Fabric CA: can't execute GetAllIdentities() after admin's affiliation change

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I registered users (with affiliation "org1.department1") using registrar Admin (without affiliation field). Then my admin is blocked because the wrong password was entered 10 times. I'm trying to get user identities using another admin (with affiliation field). Now I get error from this code block (dbaccessor.go, 592):

```
if util.ListContains(types, "*") { // If type is '*', allowed to get back of all types for requested affiliation
        query := "SELECT * FROM users WHERE ((affiliation = ?) OR (affiliation LIKE ?))"
        rows, err := d.db.Queryx("GetFilteredUsers", d.db.Rebind(query))
        if err != nil {
            return nil, errors.Wrapf(err, "Failed to execute query '%s' for affiliation '%s' and types '%s'", query, affiliation, types)
        }
        return rows, nil
    }
```

Here is err message that I get:

```
172.19.0.1:59830 GET /identities?ca=ca.rzd.wheelsets.ru 500 49 "Failed to get users by affiliation and type: Failed to execute query 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE ((affiliation = ?) OR (affiliation LIKE ?))' for affiliation 'org1.department1' and types '*': Not enough args to execute query. Expected 2, got 0."
```

Does it mean that I can't get users, that registered admin with another affiliation, right?

I need to:

(1) change either Admin password or

(2) create new admin

But in case (1) I can't issue modifyRequest, because it require affiliation (if I change it, I will lost ability to read registered identities) and in case (2) new issued admin will have affiliation field and will not be able to get identities.

Answer (score 0):

I having same issue after trying register a new Registrar user:

Identity list with admin Registrar CA works OK:

```
vagrant@vagrant:~/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/fabric-ca/org1_intermediate_client$ fabric-ca-client identity list  -u https://localhost:7154 --caname ca-org1-intermediate --tls.certfiles /home/vagrant/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/fabric-ca/org1_intermediate/ca-cert.pem
Name: admin, Type: client, Affiliation: , Max Enrollments: -1, Attributes: [{Name:hf.AffiliationMgr Value:1 ECert:false} {Name:hf.Registrar.Roles Value:* ECert:false} {Name:hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles Value:* ECert:false} {Name:hf.Revoker Value:1 ECert:false} {Name:hf.IntermediateCA Value:1 ECert:false} {Name:hf.GenCRL Value:1 ECert:false} {Name:hf.Registrar.Attributes Value:* ECert:false}]
Name: davidfdr, Type: admin, Affiliation: org1, Max Enrollments: -1, Attributes: [{Name:app1Admin Value:true ECert:true} {Name:email Value:david@gmail.com ECert:false} {Name:phone Value:5561991538000 ECert:false} {Name:hf.EnrollmentID Value:davidfdr ECert:true} {Name:hf.Type Value:admin ECert:true} {Name:hf.Affiliation Value:org1 ECert:true} {Name:hf.Revoker Value:true ECert:false}]
Name: davidfdr2, Type: admin, Affiliation: org1, Max Enrollments: -1, Attributes: [{Name:app1Admin Value:true ECert:true} {Name:email Value:david@gmail.com ECert:false} {Name:phone Value:5561991538000 ECert:false} {Name:hf.Registrar.Roles Value:* ECert:false} {Name:hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles Value:* ECert:false} {Name:hf.EnrollmentID Value:davidfdr2 ECert:true} {Name:hf.Type Value:admin ECert:true} {Name:hf.Affiliation Value:org1 ECert:true}]
Name: davidfdr3, Type: admin, Affiliation: org1, Max Enrollments: -1, Attributes: [{Name:hf.AffiliationMgr Value:true ECert:false} {Name:hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles Value:* ECert:false} {Name:app1Admin Value:true ECert:true} {Name:hf.Revoker Value:true ECert:false} {Name:hf.IntermediateCA Value:true ECert:false} {Name:hf.GenCRL Value:true ECert:false} {Name:hf.Registrar.Attributes Value:* ECert:false} {Name:hf.Registrar.Roles Value:* ECert:false} {Name:email Value:david@gmail.com ECert:false} {Name:phone Value:5561991538000 ECert:false} {Name:hf.EnrollmentID Value:davidfdr3 ECert:true} {Name:hf.Type Value:admin ECert:true} {Name:hf.Affiliation Value:org1 ECert:true}]
Name: davidfdr4, Type: admin, Affiliation: org1, Max Enrollments: -1, Attributes: [{Name:hf.AffiliationMgr Value:true ECert:false} {Name:hf.IntermediateCA Value:true ECert:false} {Name:hf.Registrar.Attributes Value:* ECert:false} {Name:hf.Registrar.Roles Value:* ECert:false} {Name:hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles Value:* ECert:false} {Name:phone Value:5561991538000 ECert:false} {Name:hf.Revoker Value:true ECert:false} {Name:hf.GenCRL Value:true ECert:false} {Name:app1Admin Value:true ECert:true} {Name:email Value:david@gmail.com ECert:false} {Name:hf.EnrollmentID Value:davidfdr4 ECert:true} {Name:hf.Type Value:admin ECert:true} {Name:hf.Affiliation Value:org1 ECert:true}]
Name: davidfdr5, Type: admin, Affiliation: org1, Max Enrollments: -1, Attributes: [{Name:hf.AffiliationMgr Value:true ECert:false} {Name:hf.IntermediateCA Value:true ECert:false} {Name:hf.Registrar.Roles Value:* ECert:false} {Name:hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles Value:* ECert:false} {Name:email Value:david@gmail.com ECert:false} {Name:phone Value:5561991538000 ECert:false} {Name:hf.Revoker Value:true ECert:false} {Name:hf.GenCRL Value:true ECert:false} {Name:hf.Registrar.Attributes Value:* ECert:false} {Name:app1Admin Value:true ECert:true} {Name:hf.EnrollmentID Value:davidfdr5 ECert:true} {Name:hf.Type Value:admin ECert:true} {Name:hf.Affiliation Value:org1 ECert:true}]
vagrant@vagrant:~/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/fabric-ca/org1_intermediate_client$
```

But after registering a new user with following command:

```
fabric-ca-client register --id.name davidfdr4 --id.secret davidfdrpw --id.type admin --id.affiliation org1 --id.attrs 'hf.AffiliationMgr=true,hf.Revoker=true,hf.IntermediateCA=true,hf.GenCRL=true,hf.Registrar.Attributes=*,hf.Registrar.Roles=*,hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles=*,app1Admin=true:ecert,email=david@gmail.com,phone=5561991538000'  --caname ca-org1-intermediate --tls.certfiles /home/vagrant/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/fabric-ca/org1_intermediate/ca-cert.pem
```

After enrolling id for user davidfdr4 and issuing a simple:

```
fabric-ca-client identity list  -u https://localhost:7154 --caname ca-org1-intermediate --tls.certfiles /home/vagrant/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/fabric-ca/org1_intermediate/ca-cert.pem
```

The server returns the same error:

```
ca_org1_intermediate|2021/08/28 21:05:25 [INFO] 172.31.0.1:45884 GET /identities?ca=ca-org1-intermediate 500 49 "Failed to get users by affiliation and type: Failed to execute query 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE ((affiliation = ?) OR (affiliation LIKE ?))' for affiliation 'org1' and types '*': not enough args to execute query: want 2 got 0"
```

Is it a BUG??
https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FABC-548